# Should we always prefer connection-pool to single connection? what's the exact benefit of using connection-pool instead of a single connection?

Tags: node.js, networking, connection-pooling

People said that connection-pool has many benefits compared to single connection:

1. In multi-threads env, a connection can not be shared by different threads(**can it really happen?**)
   [image]
2. Connection-pool can increase throughput: we can sending data more quickly by adding more connection(**is is really true?**)
3. Make program robust: we can use another connection when some disconnects

According to these benefits, i think, we should use connection-pool if and only if we are in multi-threads. But single thread env, such as Rails3, nodejs, also has connection-pool, **why?**

I'm not good at tcp/ip/socket, as i know, if the packet we send is very small(far less than MSS), a connection can be shared by multi-thread(To prove it, i had a test: client sent 236 bytes to server then receive 1306 bytes from serve, the concurrency is 500: nothing wrong happened), **so maybe packet disorder does not happen so often?**

I also had a test in nodejs: add connection-pool(https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool) to a single connection program and compare their performance. The result was beyond my expectation: connection-pool decrease the performance by at least 3 times and even worse if concurrency increases. It is because that the server replied not very quickly.

So much said, i hope some one can explain connection-pool clearly and eliminate all of my doubts and suspicions about it.

Comment: Any time you have threads you can get disordered data. You have to use a different connection per thread. No two ways about it. Connection pooling is any easy solution to this, that also conserves TCP connect/close handshakes.

Comment: So we don't need connection pool in single thread env, e.g. rails(single thread mode) or nodejs?